# Как можно "закодировать" кадры из видео opencv, чтобы потом их сравнить

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

У нас есть видео (слайд-шоу), как можно закодировать кадры из этого видео, чтобы потом сравнить их для поиска одинаковых фото?

Comment: Что значит закодировать?

Comment: Получить какиие-нибудь array, чтобы потом их сравнить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у Вас есть источник сигнала (Capture - камера, видеофайл, инет-трансляция), то очередной кадр получается из видеопотока [с помощью read](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html)

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
```

Нужны эти кадры для дальнейшего использования - храните, сколько требуется, например, в списке.